# Execute query from button - LightSwitch 2012

Tags: linq, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a custom LINQ query that I'm trying to bind to a button on a search screen. I have added a button to the screen, and modified the Can_Execute code, and added the following query.

```
    partial void DistrictQuery_Execute()
    {

        query = (from myProjects in query
                 where myProjects.SYP_PRO_DISTNO == Int16.Parse(DistrictNo)
                 orderby myProjects.SYP_PRO_DISTNO descending
                 select myProjects);
    }
```

there is an compilation error "the name 'query' does not exist in the current context". how can I wire the button to the custom query?

Comment: I'm guessing you need to declare `query` somewhere, either inside or outside that method.  Also, why is `query` being queried and also being assigned the result?

Comment: This looks like code that's been taken from a PreProcessQuery method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a *parametrised query*.

[Retrieving Information from a Data Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/ee256728.aspx)

Comment: I followed your suggestion, and was able to get close to where I wanted to be. Combined with Beth Massi's video on customizing search screens, I was able to get everything functioning. I am going to write a follow up post to detail my steps